# VCL events Handles Designer.Modified;

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

I have a `TCustomControl` descendant and I've been looking at `TGrid` as an example. In its Mouse, ScrollBar, and keyboard events, when deciding whether to call `Invalidate()`, they use these:

1. `HandleAllocated`
2. `ParentForm.ActiveControl = Self`
3. `(csDesigning in ComponentState)`
4. `ParentForm.Designer.Modified`

Now, what are the rules of when you can and should not use these tests to allow `Invalidate` to be called?  Is that the correct way of saying it?

Why is the `Handle` disappearing and not dealt with some other way?

Please tell me about `IDesigner`, as I've never used it before.

Last, is their a time when the user uses the component and the `Handle` is not available for use also?

I see the point of making an object after `TCustomControl` that tests all events in the messages with:

```
If HandleAllocated and (ParentForm.ActiveControl = Self) and (csDesigning in ComponentState)
```

I'm guessing here, but why not override `Invalidate()` and invoke `inherited Invalidate;` if a `Handle` is there, as the `Canvas` needs a `Handle`. This might be seen late but stabilizes code.

Answer (score 0):

> Now what is the rules of when you can and should not use these tests to allow Invalidate to go ahead.

The tests have nothing to do with `Invalidate()` itself. The `csDesigning` check in particular is a dead give-away that the component acts differently at design-time than it does at run-time.

> Why is the handle disappearing and not dealt with some other way.

VCL windows are not persistent.  They can and do get destroyed and recreated dynamically during the app's lifetime.  It can happen when certain properties are set, or when Forms are hidden and shown, etc.  If a component wants to use its `Handle` but not force an immediate recreation, it can check `HandleAllocated` before using the `Handle`.

> And Tell me about IDesigner as I've never used it before?

It is an interface for allowing components to interact with the Form Designer at design-time.  The most common use is to call `Designer.Modified` to let the Form Designer and Object Inspector know that something has changed that requires them to update themselves.

> Last is their a time when the user uses the component and the handle is not available for use also?

Yes, it can happen.

> If HandleAllocated and (ParentForm.ActiveControl = Self) and (csDesigning in ComponentState). I'm guessing hear, but why not override Invalidate and invoke Inherited Invalidate; if a handle is their

That would require someone to call `Invalidate()` to begin with.  And, more importantly, it would impose the restrictions on **every** call to `Invalidate()` under all circumstances, rather than imposing the restrictions only in the particular pieces of code that are acting differently at design-time vs run-time.

> as the canvas needs a handle.

The canvas handle is provided by the OS to the control during paint operations. The control is not painted when it does not have a window, though.

Comment: Ok no surprizes. So If I was writing in MouseDown and wanted to make sure I have a handle what would you use (I would use GetParentForm(Self)  first and find check for nil) then ether 1/ ParentForm.ActiveControl = Self 2/ ParentForm.SetFocus.

Comment: None of those. If your control is receiving mouse events then it (or its `Parent` control, in the case of a `TGraphicControl` descendant) must have had a valid window in order to receive the mouse messages. There is no need to check whether a window handle exists or not.

Comment: I'm trying to use TCustomControl, Are you saying the object can call events as the form is changed that can lose its handle.

Comment: `TCustomControl` is a `TWinControl` descendant, and thus has its own window, so mouse/keyboard messages are delivered directly to the control.  It has to have a valid window in order to receive them.  Which means inside your control's overridden `Key...()` and `Mouse...()` methods, its `Handle` should always be valid, which means its `Parent.Handle` window is also valid (since a child window cannot exist without a parent window), and so on all the way up to the parent `TForm.Handle` window.

Comment: I need to know that thanks. Also what is going on with my CustomControl descendant at create time when I take out of my Create; Parent := TWinControl(AOwner); Having this code in, it creates a wrong handle but without the handle I have an error message but do not know were its coming from. I guess its an event that HandleAllocated has not been checked some were. Could it be scrollbars? as TWinControl..... has no scrollbars.

Comment: It means you are doing something during construction that you should not be doing. You are correct that setting the `Parent` in the constructor is wrong. The `Parent` is assigned by the caller after construction. If you need to do something that requires the `Handle`, you have to wait until the `Parent` is assigned first, so override either the `Loaded()` and/or `SetParent()` methods.

Comment: Reading between the lines and TGrid I can get the idea a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse down gains focus. and checking focus or the handle you protect canvas errors when calling invalidate. But the idea is to identify focus before changing data.